# React Material UI Button color attribute ternary operator

Tags: reactjs, conditional-operator

I am trying to conditionally render the color of the button based on loader. Not sure what I am doing wrong on the syntax.

```
<Button type="submit" color={{ loader ? : "primary" : "disabled"}}>
  Join the Waitlist!
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`color` is waiting for a `string` not an `object`.

```
color={loader ? "primary" : "disabled"}
```

see the examples here:
https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#button

Comment: "disabled" value is not working for me (with TypeScript), I have a "No overload matches this call" error. I fixed the issue with: "color={loader ? "primary" : undefined}"

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem gave me fits till i figured out that disabled is not a value in color prop.  it is a separate prop with no = attached.  use "primary" "secondary"  "success" etc.  may fix your problem